# Why does this line run fine in script editor but not on the command line?

Tags: applescript

The line:

```
set appPath to POSIX path of alias ":Applications:iTunes.app"
```

works fine in AppleScript Editor and returns: `"/Applications/iTunes.app/"`

But when I run the following command in the terminal:

```
osascript -e 'set appPath to POSIX path of alias ":Applications:iTunes.app"'
```

I get: `15:61: syntax error: File alias :Applications:iTunes.app wasn't found. (-43)`

Why?

Comment: Try escaping out the double-quotes by putting a backslash in front of them?

Comment: I get `found unknown token` when I try that. I think the line is parsing fine, its picking out the :Applications:iTunes.app part fine, but for some reason it can't see it. Is there some environment that needs to be set up or added?

Comment: No idea. It was just a wild-ass guess. :-)

Comment: Instead of encompassing the `:Applications:iTunes.app` in one set of double quotes, try using three sets of double quotes; `"""`

Comment: Also, have a look at @regulus6633's answer (+1). The answer explains a lot about other issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you came up with ":Applications:iTunes.app"... but that is not a valid path. Colon delimited paths that are used in applescript always start with the name of your hard drive. So it should be something like "Macintosh HD:Applications:iTunes.app:". I can't tell you why it works in applescript editor (you're just lucky I guess ;)), but I'm sure if you try it the correct way it will work.

Notice that the path I used ends with a colon eg. "Macintosh HD:Applications:iTunes.app:". In general applications are package files which means they're really folders... and folders end in a colon.

Note that when you coerce a string like ":Applications:iTunes.app" to an alias (as you're doing by putting the word alias first), because it's an alias it means that the file at the path must exist. That's the definition of an alias-type path. The file must exist. ***And because the file can't possibly exist because of your incorrect path then you get the error.***

Another note: the "posix path" coercion will work on a string so you really don't need the word "alias" at all... although you may get unexpected results because as I mentioned the string portion of your path is not correct (sorry to keep saying that!).

Final note: here's one way you can find the correct applescript-style path to a file. Just run this and look at the result in AppleScript Editor. This will work for folders too if you change "file" to "folder" in the code. Try it out on an application and you will see that if the application is a package file then it will end in a colon.

```
(choose file) as text
```

Anyway, I hope that teaches you something as you go forward with your applescripting.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there a way not to have to supply the HD name? or some script to find out what the HD name is to form the correct path? The script is running on lots of different machines so I won't know the HD name unless I guess it will always be 'Macintosh HD'

Also the trailing `/` or `:` isn't essential much how `rm -r folder` and  `rm -r folder/` will both work fine on the command line

Comment: If I remove `alias` like you say and then used `"/Applications/iTunes.app"` it is working :) as you can probably tell I'm new to applescript and put the whole script together by bits an pieces I found on the net and a little guess work. I didn't actually know the meaning of alias or the colons in path names. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: "is there a way not to have to supply the HD name?"... yes because you can specify the path in the posix style using slashes, then convert that to the colon style. Here's a 2-line applescript demonstrating this...set posixPath to "/Applications/"...set macPath to (POSIX file posixPath) as text